# ROS Service How to pass array with different types?

Tags: ros

Is it possible to make a ROS service call such as the following (with different data types inside the array)?

`rosservice call /node_name/srv_name 'parameter: [one 2 3.3 four 5 6.6]'`

What would then the corresponding ROS message look like?

Comment: While it is not possible directly, maybe you can achieve something similar. I will extend my answer, but first I need some clarification: Your example looks like your array has the structure `[some_string1, some_int1, some_float1, some_string2, some_int2, some_float2, ...]`. I assume that each triple of sting, int and float belongs together, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around.
By calling the service via

```
rosservice call /node_name/srv_name 'parameter: ["one" "2" "3.3" "four" "5" "6.6"]'
```

the .srv-file can be written as

```
string[] parameter
```

and one will have to parse the strings later in C++ or Python. Much like the idea behind

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. An array in a ROS message is always of a fixed type.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more complex data types than just strings, integers and floats, you could use a message such as

```
int8 type
Type1 field1
Type2 field2
...
```

where `Type1`, `Type2`, ... are the different data types you want to use and `type` holds the information which of these field to use. If you named this message `VariableTypes`, your service-file could look like this:

```
VariableTypes[] parameters
---
```

So, when the service is called, you would have to check for each element of `parameters` which type it uses and then choose the corresponding field.

But, of course, the downside of this method is that you can produce much overhead this way.